# "any" function of "pg-promise" package does not work

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to get the data from PostgreSQL using Node.js.

So I use 'pg-promise' package.
But I can't get anything.

```
var pgp = require("pg-promise")( /*options*/ );

var db = pgp("postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/database");

db
    .any('SELECT * FROM mytable')
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log("ABC");
    });
```

I can't see the output ("ABC") on console(cmd).
I am using PostgreSQL 12.0 now.

What did I wrong?

Comment: Most likely, it fails to connect, for which you fail to provide `.catch` handler.

Comment: Doesn't work. I inserted .catch  handler with log but I can't see any log.